# Does kafka salesforce-bulk-source-connector work with Amazon MSK?

Tags: salesforce, apache-kafka-connect, aws-msk

happy new am experimenting with Kafka for the first time, i set up an AWS MSK Kafka cluster successfully, next step in my experiment is the using kafka-connect and in particular i want to use the salesforce-bulk-source connector, according to the documentation its say that this connector is a proprietary connector and it requires a confluent license as part of the configuration as well as a topic where to store [here](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-salesforce-bulk-api/current/source/configuration_options.html#salesforce-bulk-api-source-connector-config) the confluent platform configuration, my question, does this connector work with an MSK cluster or would it require my cluster to be on the confluent platform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the connector regardless of your Kafka cluster. You will need to run your own Kafka Connect worker, configured to use your Kafka cluster.

As you have noted, it is a proprietary connector and therefore:

- You can use it with a 30-day free trial
- or under the Developer Licence indefinitely if you have just a single Kafka broker

Here's an example of a [Docker Compose to run Kafka Connect docker image](https://github.com/confluentinc/demo-scene/blob/master/build-a-streaming-pipeline/docker-compose.yml#L74-L107).

---

Edit: *You cannot use Confluent connectors that require a commercial license with MSK. You need a valid Confluent subscription.*